# Populate RadioButton when clicking on listview c#

Tags: c#, binding, radio-button

I have created a form application with a lot of entries coming from text boxes, a date time picker and radio buttons. Once the user fills in this information they can click a button that fills it into a listview. I then want it so when the user clicks on the listview that it fills in the text boxes, date time picker and radio buttons with what they had entered. I was able to do this for the text boxes and date time picker easily enough but I am struggling to find out how to select the radio button they selected when they entered the data. My code is this:

```
private void lview_Bonds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lview_Bonds.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            txt_Cusip.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            txt_Ticker.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
            txt_Name.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            cld_Maturity.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
            txt_Coupon.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
            cmb_PrimaryBook.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text;
            cmb_AssignedBook.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[6].Text;

            if (lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text == "Fixed")
            {
                rdbtn_Fixed.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text;
            }
            else
            {
                rdbtn_Zero.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text;
            }

            txt_Position.Text = lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[8].Text;
        }

    }
```

The if statement for the radio button didn't work. From researching, it seems I need to do something with binding but this is a new concept to me! I have only been doing c# for about 2 weeks so I'm not too sure how to bind this data from the listview to the entry fields!

Any help or advice would be great!

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you try debugging with breakpoints? Are you trying to select the RadioButton or set its text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to select/check the radiobuttons
Look at this:

[MSDN RadioButton.Checked Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx)

```
if (lview_Bonds.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[7].Text == "Fixed")
{
    rdbtn_Fixed.Checked = true;
}
else
{
    rdbtn_Zero.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to set the text of the radio-buttons, not the checked-value

Comment: No actually what he said worked fine! I just wanted to radio button to be selected when I clicked on the listview and that worked. So, many thanks for your help!!